# How do I create a population sample that follows specified demographics?

Tags: algorithm, statistics

I have the following class:

```
class Person
{
  GenderEnum Gender;
  RaceEnum Race;
  double Salary;
  ...
}
```

I want to create 1000 instances of this class such that the collection of 1000 Persons follow these 5 demographic statistics:

1. 50% male; 50% female
2. 55% white; 20% black; 15% Hispanic; 5% Asian; 2% Native American; 3% Other;
3. 10% < $10K; 15% $10K-$25K; 35% $25K-$50K; 20% $50K-$100K; 15% $100K-$200K; 5% over $200K
4. Mean salary for females is 77% of mean salary for males
5. Mean Salary as a percentage of mean white salary:
   white - 100%.
   black - 75%.
   Hispanic - 83%.
   Asian - 115%.
   Native American - 94%.
   Other - 100%.

The categories above are exactly what I want but the percentages given are just examples.  The actual percentages will be inputs to my application and will be based on what district my application is looking at.

How can I accomplish this?

**What I've tried:**

I can pretty easily create 1000 instances of my Person class and assign the Gender and race to match my demographics.  (For my project I'm assuming male/female ratio is independent of race).  I can also randomly create a list of salaries based on the specified percentage brackets.  Where I run into trouble is figuring out how to assign those salaries to my Person instances in such a way that the mean salaries across gender and mean salaries across race match the specified conditions.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that item 3 is the income distribution for the entire population? and therefore the income distribution for white males will be skewed toward higher values than that, and the income distribution for everyone else will be skewed toward lower values?

Comment: Yes item 3 is the income distribution for the entire population.  So if you were looking at the income distribution of only white males, the brackets themselves would stay the same, but the percentage representation would be skewed higher in the higher income brackets, yes.  So for example, you might see 18% (vs. 15%) in the 100K-200K and 8% (vs. 5%) in the > 200K if the percentages were out of white male population only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this by assuming that the distribution of income for all categories is the same shape as the one you gave, but scaled by a factor which makes all the values larger or smaller. That is, the income distribution has the same number of bars and the same mass proportion in each bar, but the bars are shifted towards smaller values or towards larger values, and all bars are shifted by the same factor.

If that's reasonable, then this has an easy solution. Note that the mean value of the income distribution over all people is `sum(p[i]*c[i], i, 1, #bars)`, which I'll call `M`, where `p[i]` = mass proportion of bar `i` and `c[i]` = center of bar `i`. For each group `j`, you have the mean `sum(s[j]*p[i]*c[i], i, 1, #bars) = s[j]*M` where `s[j]` is the scale factor for group `j`. Furthermore you know that the overall mean is equal to the sum of the means of the groups, weighting each by the proportion of people in that category, i.e. `M = sum(s[j]*M*q[j], j, 1, #groups)` where `q[j]` is the proportion of people in the group. Finally you are given specific values for the mean of each group relative to the mean for white people, i.e. you know `(s[j]*M)/(s[k]*M) = s[j]/s[k]` = some fraction, where `k` is the index for the white group. From this much you can solve these equations for `s[k]` (the scaling factor for the white group) and then `s[j]` from that.

I've spelled this out for the racial groups only. You can repeat the process for men versus women, starting with the distribution you found for each racial group and finding an additional scaling factor. I would guess that if you did it the other way, gender first and then race, you would get the same results, but although it seems obvious I wouldn't be sure unless I worked out a proof of it.

Comment: You got it! Thanks.  I figure I can mix gender and race to make more groups (black men, black women, white men, white women, etc.) and then do your process once instead of twice.  The equations for race and gender combined are simple. BF = 0.77*BM; (BF + BM)/2 = black salary mean;  Thanks again!